# Java 8 - How to get single values out of Map of Lists?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have the following Map `Map<List<String>, String>` with the following example values:

```
List["Los Angeles", "New York", "Chicago"] -> "USA",
List["Toronto", "Vancover", "Montréal"] -> "Canada"
```

Is it possible to get a Map `Map<String, String>` and map every element of the value list to it's key? Example:

```
"Los Angeles" -> "USA",
"New York" -> "USA",
"Chicago" -> "USA",
"Toronto" -> "Canada",
...
```

I need it in a stream, that afterwords I can sort.

Comment: Could be an X Y problem. What is your ultimate goal? The point of a `Map` is to map keys to values. You can't map the key "USA" to multiple values. You could use another data structure (at the cost of performance), or keep it the way it is.

Comment: if you have it like that, what should that theoretical Map give you when you ask - give me "USA" value?

Comment: What does this have to do with `Set`?

Comment: @Eugene I just need to call the List with stream and iterate over the list of keys to get them in the way i need.

Comment: @sleepToken yes I just wrote it wrong. When i have a List of Keys now and a single value, how can i get with stream to my wished result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it is possible:

```
 Map<List<String>, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(List.of("Los Angeles", "New York", "Chicago"), "USA");
    map.put(List.of("Toronto", "Vancover", "Montréal"), "Canada");

    Map<String, String> newMap = map.entrySet().stream().flatMap(entry -> entry.getKey().stream().map(city -> Map.entry(city, entry.getValue()))).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

An example output:

> {New York=USA, MontrÃ©al=Canada, Chicago=USA, Vancover=Canada, Los Angeles=USA, Toronto=Canada}

First, you have to [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) on the [`entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entrySet())'s [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) where you can `map` the keys to a new `Stream` of entries for example.

As you mentioned you need it as a `Stream`, so probably you want to stop before `collect`:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
  .flatMap(entry -> entry.getKey().stream()
    .map(city -> Map.entry(city, entry.getValue())))
```

(Those entries you can collect to a new `Map`.)